# Start and Stop Thread in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm building web app using django. I need to use lots of multithreading. Here I have to add features to start or stop specific thread, I didn't know what to use to achieve this. Here can I use django celery?, but i also need to implement to stop that task. Any suggestion would be appreciated.  Eg:
[image]

Comment: should i use multiprocessing or multithreading, or django-celery

Comment: it's better to use celery and u can stop celery tasks manually just u need to save the task_id to be able to sop it .

Comment: i have an idea it may help u , the idea main to create a class for that  object that class contain task_id and some details maybe u need such as starting time ....etc , and u can display this objects on ur view .